# Execute nltk.stem.SnowballStemmer in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk

I have a four column DataFrame with two columns of tokenized words that have had stop words removed and converted to lower case and am now attempting to stem.

[image]

I'm not sure if the `apply()` method accesses the series plus its individual cells or if I need another way of stepping into each record so tried both (I think!)

`from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer`
`stemmer = nltk.stem.SnowballStemmer('english')`

I've tried:

`df_2['Headline'] = df_2['Headline'].apply(lambda x: stemmer.stem(item) for item in x)`

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 df_2['Headline__'] = df_2['Headline'].apply(lambda x: stemmer.stem(item) for item in x)
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\learn-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py
>   in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)    3192
>   else:    3193                 values = self.astype(object).values
>   -> 3194                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)    3195     3196         if len(mapped) and
>   isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
>
> pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()
>
> TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable

I believe this TypeError is similar to the one that says 'List' object is not callable and fixed that one with the `apply()` method and out of ideas here.

`df_2['Headline'] = df_2['Headline'].apply(lambda x: stemmer.stem(x))`

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 df_2['Headline'] = df_2['Headline'].apply(lambda x: stemmer.stem(x))
>         2 
>         3 df_2.head()
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\learn-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py
>   in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)    3192
>   else:    3193                 values = self.astype(object).values
>   -> 3194                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)    3195     3196         if len(mapped) and
>   isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
>
> pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()
>
> in (x)
>   ----> 1 df_2['Headline'] = df_2['Headline'].apply(lambda x: stemmer.stem(x))
>         2 
>         3 df_2.head()
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\learn-env\lib\site-packages\nltk\stem\snowball.py
>   in stem(self, word)    1415     1416         """
>   -> 1417         word = word.lower()    1418     1419         if word in self.stopwords or len(word) <= 2:
>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: could you share some sample data?

Comment: @politicalscientist, just added a snapshot of the DF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `axis` for the `apply`.

Here is a full working example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_1' : [['ducks'], ['dogs']],
    'col_2' : [['he', 'eats', 'apples'], ['she', 'has', 'cats', 'dogs']],
    'col_3' : ['some data 1', 'some data 2'],
    'col_4' : ['another data 1', 'another data 2']
})
df.head()
```

**Output**

```
    col_1   col_2                   col_3       col_4
0   [ducks] [he, eats, apples]      some data 1 another data 1
1   [dogs]  [she, has, cats, dogs]  some data 2 another data 2
```

Now let us apply stemming for the tokenized columns:

```py
import nltk
from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer
stemmer = nltk.stem.SnowballStemmer('english')

df.col_1 = df.apply(lambda row: [stemmer.stem(item) for item in row.col_1], axis=1)
df.col_2 = df.apply(lambda row: [stemmer.stem(item) for item in row.col_2], axis=1)
```

Check the new content of the dataframe.

```py
df.head()
```

**Output**

```
    col_1   col_2                   col_3       col_4
0   [duck]  [he, eat, appl]         some data 1 another data 1
1   [dog]   [she, has, cat, dog]    some data 2 another data 2
```

Comment: thanks @hzitoun!  Just when I think I have lambdas and list comprehensions figured out, I get brought back down to reality, ha!

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer
stemmer = SnowballStemmer(language='english')

data = {'Tokens': [['I', 'am', 'playing', 'football'],
               ['He', 'is', 'eating', 'an', 'apple'],
               ['She', 'is', 'reading', 'a', 'book']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def stem_tokens(tokens):
stemmed_tokens = [stemmer.stem(token) for token in tokens]
return stemmed_tokens

df['Stemmed_Tokens'] = df['Tokens'].apply(stem_tokens)
```

Comment: It would be much better if you provide more supporting information to your answer.